# How to custom log format when use zap?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

Currently, our project's log format is like:

```
www.abcdef.com`3`1s
```

I want to use Go to rewrite project and import zap as log tool. By zap the log's format is like:

```
{"url": "www.abcdef.com", "attempt": 3, "backoff": "1s"}
```

I google its usage, but I don't find out any way that changes zap's format to above mentioned, so I want to seek some advice here.

Comment: I found out the way to record complete string format.

The `zapcore` support a struct EncoderConfig. When I set matter keys empty value, zap doesn't record info of these keys. Config is like this:

`cfg := zapcore.EncoderConfig{
 TimeKey:        "",
 LevelKey:       "",
 NameKey:        "",
 CallerKey:      "",
 MessageKey:     "M",
 StacktraceKey:  ""
}`

Anyway, thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

set `EncoderConfig`

```golang
cfg := zapcore.EncoderConfig{ 
    TimeKey: "", 
    LevelKey: "", 
    NameKey: "", 
    CallerKey: "", 
    MessageKey: "M", 
    StacktraceKey: "",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example configuration here:

```golang
        config := zap.NewProductionConfig()

        config.EncoderConfig.EncodeTime = zapcore.TimeEncoderOfLayout(time.RFC3339)

        logger, _ := config.Build()
```

Check `EncoderConfig` in the source code, to find out what you can customize:

https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/master/zapcore/encoder.go#L316

Answer (score 0):

Zap allows to [customize encoders](https://blog.sandipb.net/2018/05/03/using-zap-creating-custom-encoders/). In the linked article author sets a field `EncodeLevel` of [EncoderConfig](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore#EncoderConfig) to a custom function. That way you can change encoding of logging level, timestamp, duration, caller and logger name.

You also can use [zap.RegisterEncoder](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap#RegisterEncoder) to add your custom encoder and then set `Encoding` field in [config](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap#Config) to the name of your encoder.

Keep in mind that encoder is used on every call of a logging methods, so it must have a good perfomance.